# load lib .so with jna

Tags: java, c++, global-variables, jna, .so

I am actually trying to open a library. So (I did it in c++) with JNA 
my problem is that I can not open a library when there is a static variable. However I have to use un singleton in my library so I am looking for why a static variable can not be use with JNA to prove it a made a little library

there is the .h file:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED1_LIBRARY_H
#define UNTITLED1_LIBRARY_H
#include <iostream>
class library {
 private:
  static char* h;
 public:
  int hello();
};

extern "C" int hello(){
 library lib;
 return lib.hello();
}

#endif
```

then my .cpp file:

```
#include "library.h"
#include "ecrire.h"

#include <iostream>

int library::hello() {
 h = (char*)"hello world";
 std::cout<<h<<std::endl;
 return 45;
}
```

then my java class and interface

```
public class Westgard {
static {       
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path","../logic/resources/calculator"); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int maj = InterfaceLibWestgard.INSTANCE.hello();
    System.out.println(maj);
}

}


import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface InterfaceLibWestgard extends Library {
  int hello();
  static InterfaceLibWestgard INSTANCE = (InterfaceLibWestgard) 
  Native.loadLibrary("../logic/resources/calculator/libuntitled1.so", 
  InterfaceLibWestgard.class);
}
```

So if I try like this it wont work but when a remove the static from the .h it works does not anyone know why I have been looking for since 4-5 hours still do not know why...

This is my issue log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load 
 library '../logic/resources/calculator/libuntitled1.so': Native library 
(linux-x86-64/../logic/resources/calculator/libuntitled1.so) not found in 
resource path ([file:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/resources.jar,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `library::h` but not defined it. You need to add

```
char* library::h = 0;
```

in your cpp file.

Presumably the library is either failing to compile or it is compiling but expecting this missing symbol to be defined in another library.

Comment: @CharlesSocié please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Native.load()` instead of `Native.loadLibrary()`.

Check the code below,

```
    public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
        int myMethod();
    }

    static {
        MyLibrary lib = (MyLibrary)Native.load("untitled1" , MyLibrary.class);
    }
```

You can add the file in the resource location and load it in the above manner easily. You should exclude the "lib" prefix and ".so" file type. In your case,

filename = "untitled1"

[Using JNA to Access Native Dynamic Libraries](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jna-dynamic-libraries)